# How does pet insurance work for leagues?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

When I got my Phoenix, I also received a game message saying "Your new pet has been automatically insured". In the main game, pet insurance is run through [Probita](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Probita) in East Ardougne. If you die with an insured pet, you may rebuy that pet from Probita for 1 million gp. However, you can't exactly travel to East Ardougne to rebuy a pet in the Twisted League, so how does the automatic pet insurance work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The League Tutor, located in Kourend Castle Courtyard, will allow you to reclaim lost pets. Note that it is not clear whether this will cost 1 million gp.

From the wiki page about the Twisted League update (emphasis mine):

> League-to-League Pets
>
> Any insured pets gained in the previous League will carry over to the
>   next one.
>
> **The League Tutor will allow you to reclaim your pets if you
>   lose them.**

[Source](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Update:The_Twisted_League)

@Cookiezzz has shared with us that reclaiming the pet is, in fact, **free**! Any costs that are applied in the normal game, should not apply in Twisted League.

Comment: If anyone has lost their pets and reclaimed them, please let us know whether the costs is applicable in Twisted League.

Answer (score 1):

Just reclaimed a pet. It was free.

Comment: This is extremely good info, however, it is more of a comment than a standalone answer. If you can flesh this out to be more complete (including where and how), that would be extremely good

Comment: I've added a section mentioning this in my answer, if that's okay. Thank you for sharing this information!